# JqGrid FormEdit doesnt Show Form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to implement form editing in my jqgrid. I am loading json data from server side. everything goes fine. But when i try to edit using edit button. it shows "Please, select row" warning. same error for delete and view, but Add works fine. I even tried onClickrow editform. but my form doesnt pop up. Any idea??

Below are my code

```
var insptrackgrid = $("#insptracktbl");

insptrackgrid.jqGrid({    //17 cols
    datatype: "json",
    url:"/Myelclass/InspectionTrackAction.do?event=load", 

    colNames:['ID','Status','CtNo','InspDate','QCtlr','ArticleID','Article','Color','InspCdn','testID','GradeId','RejID','TotInspctd','comments'],  
    colModel :[ 
                {name: 'inspid', index: 'inspid', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'status', index: 'status', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'inspContractNo', index: 'contractno', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'inspdate', index: 'inspdate', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'inspqualityctrlr', index: 'qualitycontroller', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'articleid', index: 'articleid', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'article', index: 'article', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'color', index: 'color', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'inspcdn', index: 'inspcdn', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'testid', index: 'testid', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'gradeid', index: 'gradeid', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'rejectsid', index: 'rejectsid', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'totinspected', index: 'totinspected', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
                {name: 'inspcomments', index: 'inspcomments', align:'center', width:60, editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, 
                },
    ],
    jsonReader : {  
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "rows",
        page: "page", //calls first
        total: "total" ,//calls Second
        records: "records" //calls Third
    },  
    caption: "Inspection Tracking Report",
    pager: "#insptrackpager",
    rowNum: 10, 
    rowList:[20,30,40],
    loadtext: "Bow Bow",
    height : "auto",
    width:"auto",  
    sortname: "contractno", 
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    editurl:"/Myelclass/InspectionTrackAction.do?event=edit",
    emptyrecords: "No records to display",
    /*onSelectRow: function () {
        alert("rows selected");
    },*/
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
        alert("Double Click ");
        $(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid); // this never Called 
        alert("Double Click 2");
    },


    });
insptrackgrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#insptrackpager',{
        edit: true,
        add: true,
        del: true, 
        search: true, 
        view: true, 
        });
```

## UPDATE

I am Attaching two images for ref. [image: Loaded Data] 
[image: While Editing]
Image 1 shows data loaded.
Image 2 shows Data selected to be edited. here i have selected ID=4 for editing

Comment: You must click a row before you edit/remove it. Have you done that?

Comment: Your code seems fine. If you don't have any data loaded, this could happen.

Comment: @Soony i did. the problem is always first row gets selected. and moreover ondblClickRow method editGridRow is never called.

Comment: @Soony i do have data loaded. say abt 5 rows

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. I just tested it. Check if there are other scripts that could affect it. Or, just check your mouse.

Comment: @Soony mouse is working fine and i didnt find any other scripts affecting my code. seems confusing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ondblClickRow` function, change the `editGridRow` line to:

```
insptrackgrid.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid);
```

Does this help at all?

Comment: @FastTrack.thanks for response. Still not working.    the issue is always first row is highlighted irrespective of what rows i selected.   guess some css issues.   any idea??